# Nvidia-460 Driver and GL Updates greatly affect performance on dual monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors

The recent updates to NVidia-460 including GL libs kill the performance on one of two monitors connected via thunderbolt on my Thinkpad (T25). By killing it, I mean the lag on one (it can vary which) increases to the point of making the screen unusable. When or if it is usable, it tears and lags terribly.

```
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
```

I was fortunate enough to be able to roll back to 450, but I can now no longer accept any of the updates, which renders Ubuntu pretty useless to me right now. Not sure where things broke, but finding very little information about this issue. Not sure where to proceed next, but some confirmation and/or a bug to track? I fortunately have two identical laptops at my disposal, and I verified the 460 update breaks my secondary as well, so I can't be the only one with this issue. I see some other related posts, but no verified responses in how to resolve.
I need some reliable path forward, but not sure how to get that from Ubuntu at the moment. Not being able to do updates is not a LongTermSolution....help!